# Scipy curve_fit error, no optimal parameters

Tags: numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to use the scipy.optimize.curve_fit but I encounter an error - `RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.`

I have data points for the morse potential function and I am trying to extract the three parameters D, alpha and r_eq

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



z_top = np.array([-2.0, -1.9733333333333334, -1.9466666666666668, -1.92, -1.8933333333333333, -1.8666666666666667, -1.84, -1.8133333333333332, -1.7866666666666666, -1.76, -1.7333333333333334, -1.7066666666666666, -1.68, -1.6533333333333333, -1.6266666666666667, -1.6, -1.5733333333333333, -1.5466666666666666, -1.52, -1.4933333333333332, -1.4666666666666668, -1.44, -1.4133333333333333, -1.3866666666666667, -1.3599999999999999, -1.3333333333333333, -1.3066666666666666, -1.2799999999999998, -1.2533333333333334, -1.2266666666666666, -1.2, -1.1733333333333333, -1.1466666666666665, -1.12, -1.0933333333333333, -1.0666666666666667, -1.04, -1.0133333333333332, -0.9866666666666666, -0.96, -0.9333333333333333, -0.9066666666666665, -0.8799999999999999, -0.8533333333333333, -0.8266666666666667, -0.7999999999999998, -0.7733333333333332, -0.7466666666666666, -0.72, -0.6933333333333334, -0.6666666666666665, -0.6399999999999999, -0.6133333333333333, -0.5866666666666667, -0.5599999999999998, -0.5333333333333332, -0.5066666666666666, -0.48, -0.45333333333333314, -0.4266666666666665, -0.3999999999999999, -0.3733333333333333, -0.34666666666666646, -0.31999999999999984, -0.2933333333333332, -0.2666666666666666, -0.24, -0.21333333333333315, -0.18666666666666654, -0.15999999999999992, -0.1333333333333333, -0.10666666666666647, -0.07999999999999985, -0.05333333333333323, -0.026666666666666616, 0.0, 0.02666666666666684, 0.05333333333333368, 0.08000000000000007, 0.10666666666666691, 0.1333333333333333, 0.16000000000000014, 0.18666666666666698, 0.21333333333333337, 0.2400000000000002, 0.2666666666666666, 0.29333333333333345, 0.3200000000000003, 0.3466666666666667, 0.3733333333333335, 0.40000000000000036, 0.42666666666666675, 0.4533333333333336, 0.48, 0.5066666666666668, 0.5333333333333337, 0.56, 0.5866666666666669, 0.6133333333333333, 0.6400000000000001, 0.666666666666667, 0.6933333333333334, 0.7200000000000002, 0.746666666666667, 0.7733333333333334, 0.8000000000000003, 0.8266666666666667, 0.8533333333333335, 0.8800000000000003, 0.9066666666666667, 0.9333333333333336, 0.9600000000000004, 0.9866666666666668, 1.0133333333333336, 1.04, 1.0666666666666669, 1.0933333333333337, 1.12, 1.146666666666667, 1.1733333333333333, 1.2000000000000002, 1.226666666666667, 1.2533333333333334, 1.2800000000000002, 1.306666666666667, 1.3333333333333335, 1.3600000000000003, 1.3866666666666667, 1.4133333333333336, 1.4400000000000004, 1.4666666666666668, 1.4933333333333336, 1.52, 1.5466666666666669, 1.5733333333333337, 1.6, 1.626666666666667, 1.6533333333333338, 1.6800000000000002, 1.706666666666667, 1.7333333333333334, 1.7600000000000002, 1.786666666666667, 1.8133333333333335, 1.8400000000000003, 1.8666666666666667, 1.8933333333333335, 1.9200000000000004, 1.9466666666666668, 1.9733333333333336, 2.0, 2.0266666666666673, 2.0533333333333337, 2.08, 2.1066666666666674, 2.1333333333333337, 2.16, 2.1866666666666665, 2.213333333333334, 2.24, 2.2666666666666666, 2.293333333333334, 2.3200000000000003, 2.3466666666666667, 2.373333333333334, 2.4000000000000004, 2.4266666666666667, 2.453333333333334, 2.4800000000000004, 2.506666666666667, 2.533333333333333, 2.5600000000000005, 2.586666666666667, 2.6133333333333333, 2.6400000000000006, 2.666666666666667, 2.6933333333333334, 2.7200000000000006, 2.746666666666667, 2.7733333333333334, 2.8000000000000007, 2.826666666666667, 2.8533333333333335, 2.88, 2.906666666666667, 2.9333333333333336, 2.96, 2.9866666666666672, 3.0133333333333336, 3.04, 3.0666666666666673, 3.0933333333333337, 3.12, 3.1466666666666674, 3.173333333333334, 3.2, 3.2266666666666666, 3.253333333333334, 3.2800000000000002, 3.3066666666666666, 3.333333333333334, 3.3600000000000003, 3.3866666666666667, 3.413333333333334, 3.4400000000000004, 3.466666666666667, 3.493333333333334, 3.5200000000000005, 3.546666666666667, 3.5733333333333333, 3.6000000000000005, 3.626666666666667, 3.6533333333333333, 3.6800000000000006, 3.706666666666667, 3.7333333333333334, 3.7600000000000007, 3.786666666666667, 3.8133333333333335, 3.8400000000000007, 3.866666666666667, 3.8933333333333335, 3.920000000000001, 3.946666666666667, 3.9733333333333336, 4.0, 4.026666666666667, 4.053333333333334, 4.08, 4.106666666666667, 4.133333333333334, 4.16, 4.186666666666667, 4.213333333333334, 4.24, 4.2666666666666675, 4.293333333333334, 4.32, 4.346666666666667, 4.373333333333334, 4.4, 4.426666666666667, 4.453333333333334, 4.48, 4.506666666666667, 4.533333333333334, 4.5600000000000005, 4.586666666666667, 4.613333333333334, 4.640000000000001, 4.666666666666667, 4.693333333333333, 4.720000000000001, 4.746666666666667, 4.773333333333333, 4.800000000000001, 4.826666666666667, 4.8533333333333335, 4.880000000000001, 4.906666666666667, 4.933333333333334, 4.960000000000001, 4.986666666666667, 5.013333333333334, 5.04, 5.066666666666667, 5.093333333333334, 5.12, 5.146666666666667, 5.173333333333334, 5.2, 5.2266666666666675, 5.253333333333334, 5.28, 5.3066666666666675, 5.333333333333334, 5.36, 5.386666666666667, 5.413333333333334, 5.44, 5.466666666666667, 5.493333333333334, 5.5200000000000005, 5.546666666666667, 5.573333333333334, 5.6000000000000005, 5.626666666666667, 5.653333333333334, 5.680000000000001, 5.706666666666667, 5.733333333333333, 5.760000000000001, 5.786666666666667, 5.8133333333333335, 5.840000000000001, 5.866666666666667, 5.8933333333333335, 5.920000000000001, 5.946666666666667, 5.973333333333334])
p_top = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 52.872576794481944, 60.36328831067402, 68.58181676019626, 77.54010551102007, 87.24546077586182, 97.71380116903708, 108.97588971792945, 121.1230000000001, 134.28859358309765, 148.68731887019467, 164.5633871885017, 182.18666227169558, 201.83818349095438, 223.81267643614873, 248.42818042617202, 276.03506399135284, 307.0337209116861, 341.87896590372986, 381.1192679598341, 425.3893723626624, 475.5021283556349, 532.4158997232969, 597.4090000000003, 672.0410742621983, 758.533379251738, 859.7165530846363, 979.6593316087284, 1124.0206760913093, 1301.1409742106393, 1519.6640526904762, 1788.227505227972, 2115.468518070886, 2510.024265626171, 2980.5319397027483, 3535.6285264165717, 4183.950889387946, 4934.135917372832, 5794.82045, 4934.420403031789, 4184.487017193709, 3536.3779199568417, 2981.450849155281, 2511.0636810971228, 2116.574298226707, 1789.340587092605, 1520.720465547997, 1302.0718287570105, 1124.752573196128, 980.1205102605351, 859.8428649405212, 758.281365651945, 671.394251505908, 596.3759999999991, 531.0259774866203, 473.7897372355332, 423.3784182587137, 378.7905732211398, 339.2052390738119, 304.05693724550565, 272.8094869362206, 244.93161029019166, 220.00582429999793, 197.7284586919518, 177.8007936067852, 159.92938926933715, 143.86679302868998, 129.3920578431436, 116.3009999999999, 104.39987683440208, 93.51271797907324, 83.48433620575351, 74.20490406269317, 65.59711336145308, 57.63198789171022, 50.29487274165398, 43.58296879663324, 37.48630089022281, 31.9864346061135, 27.059460686269396, 22.676772829659317, 18.800931214057726, 15.390398961980129, 12.405999999999976, 9.808750398065335, 7.556975821856745, 5.609771290609389, 3.930241859207573, 2.4840486871436225, 1.2405555333284073, 0.17249876364223482, -0.7431963631258247, -1.527178008314559, -2.1976614885762182, -2.7685586963324997, -3.2507065483663036, -3.654521247585481, -3.989819778712002, -4.264, -4.483339654609878, -4.653107428963594, -4.778317791591804, -4.863979954625947, -4.914753159149808, -4.934618850520453, -4.92747858548951, -4.8971925826874845, -4.846723689404206, -4.778134576732593, -4.693446251582014, -4.5947146119860145, -4.483931113002393, -4.363044061334697, -4.234, -4.0985235604644705, -3.9574567255996067, -3.811418823406809, -3.661031677747074, -3.507335845802052, -3.3521869245809506, -3.197532929895521, -3.045306521322895, -2.897111875210079, -2.7542247897630006, -2.6179055748822746, -2.4892499037088855, -2.3679261099625046, -2.2528674758007727, -2.142999999999998, -2.03745860943027, -1.936218329497232, -1.8394781167611673, -1.747441997712195, -1.6600861278953287, -1.5769440991709724, -1.4974984903385995, -1.4212457390197035, -1.3480060418851023, -1.277923339237923, -1.2111555085799302, -1.1478331446399963, -1.0878510870420735, -1.030982650405997, -0.9769999999999986, -0.9257060180247605, -0.8770268056960342, -0.8309191877527421, -0.7873394579322428, -0.7462046341344566, -0.707355543280765, -0.6706241363212588, -0.6358440114180867, -0.6028906779941965, -0.5716816224666781, -0.542135986875562, -0.514173025332713, -0.4877142855378665, -0.4626824379381182, -0.43899999999999995, -0.4165943842589561, -0.3954130579480966, -0.37540839142719296, -0.35653259042310337, -0.3387377083468086, -0.3219756460666744, -0.3061981561026408, -0.2913568256017715, -0.27740309673209135, -0.26428826973514485, -0.25196348850713185, -0.24038028798051297, -0.22949466726113874, -0.21926484416543945, -0.20964892669615007, -0.20060488653428893, -0.19209054169683576, -0.18406358448408644, -0.17648157320150093, -0.16930192351620832, -0.1624822410268282, -0.15599398273189863, -0.1498278946257743, -0.143976027663664, -0.1384303016449746, -0.13318251846105061, -0.1282243553559818, -0.12354735885956175, -0.11914296564285694, -0.115, -0.11110306063818942, -0.10743823387446969, -0.10399057427215586, -0.10074506770538746, -0.09768595719983417, -0.09478686404733155, -0.09203198506265693, -0.08941054762959841, -0.0869117305275437, -0.08452465786411881, -0.08223840650397521, -0.08004200111956421, -0.07792441608596867, -0.07587457925344288, -0.07388137031451006, -0.0719336220194075, -0.07002011928032632, -0.06812960289914699, -0.06625080975713306, -0.06437774354263374, -0.062514670658265, -0.06066699908536895, -0.058840093159610946, -0.05703927761570363, -0.055269833348506214, -0.053537002547862714, -0.05184598638412147, -0.05020194624570422, -0.048609299571983254, -0.0470683062510954, -0.04557769671809728, -0.04413616149903207, -0.04274235499024258, -0.04139489568258407, -0.04009236691353722, -0.03883331623326931, -0.037616257023266514, -0.03643968154837971, -0.03530235422607354, -0.03420331195177105, -0.03314152488588915, -0.032107966203906546, -0.031098116639678777, -0.03011436052645273, -0.029159083111374974, -0.02823466944709844, -0.027343502994046268, -0.026487055881413483, -0.025664282278113962, -0.024873704934188466, -0.024113846492361448, -0.023383229629240988, -0.022680377059935815, -0.022003811622373776, -0.02135205612181401, -0.020723633222147094, -0.020117107909086978, -0.01953141316798061, -0.01896567156149227, -0.018419007242562745, -0.017890544187225972, -0.017379406521364806, -0.016884718251067944, -0.016405603478766607, -0.015941186322196526, -0.015490596420519654, -0.01505321655270402, -0.014628780797528938, -0.014217049100448345, -0.01381778138256858, -0.01343073756640109, -0.013055677585210439, -0.012692361374500867, -0.012340548869974452]) 


def leps(z, D, alpha, r_eq):
    
    return (D*(np.exp(-2*alpha*(z - r_eq)) - 2*np.exp(-alpha*(z - r_eq))))



popt, pcov = curve_fit(leps, z_top, p_top)
print(popt)


plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(z_top,p_top,label='data')
plt.plot(z_top, leps(z_top, *popt), 'r-',label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.ylim(-8,1)
```

EDIT:

[image]

the fit is very poor, even after providing starting parameters. How do you determine the optimal parameters for a good fit?

Comment: `-alpha(z - r_eq)` should be `-alpha*(z - r_eq)`

Comment: @PéterLeéh thank you ! but it still doesn't give me the parameters. I have edited the question for the runtime error

Comment: You need to provide reasonable initial fitting parameters. This can be done with the `p0` argument of `curve_fit`.

Comment: @PéterLeéh I am sorry but how do you find the right start parameters?

Comment: There is no general way to find them. Try to think about what do you expect them to be. Look at the plot, or try to guess from the real physical meaning of the parameters (in case it's from a measurement).